# How to get access to the snakmake options inside the Snakefile

Tags: snakemake

In particular, I want to access to the notemp option, to remove "onsucces" additionnal temp files, if and only if the notemp option is False.

I want to do that because I have a very basic rule for bgzip vcf files, and I can't define its outputs as `temp()` because this rules is used to generate temporary files but also my final ouput files.

### EDIT

temporary files are not removed if they correspond to inputs of an other rule AND if that rule do something, which is not the case of the rule `all`.
Here is an example:

```
rule all:
    input: "output2.gz"

rule zcat:
    input : "output.gz"
    output: temp("output2")
    shell:
        "zcat {input} > {output}"

rule cp:
    input : "input"
    output: temp("output")
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"

rule gzip :
    input:"{file}"
    output: temp("{file}.gz")
    shell:
        "gzip -c {input} > {output}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could scan the list `sys.argv` for the presence of the notemp flag taking care that options may be specified at the command line in shorter form if they are unambiguous. E.g. `--not` is the same as `--notemp`.

Most importantly,

> I can't define its outputs as temp() because this rules is used to generate temporary files but also my final ouput files

This suggests to me that you are not correctly specifying input and output files in your rules as snakemake will not delete temp files that are still required. It may be that a necessary file is produced in output but it is not listed as input where necessary. For example, here below rule `parse_bam` will fail because samtools requires the .bai index. The index is correctly created in rule `bam` but deleted immediately because of the `temp` flag. The solution is to list `a.bam.bai` as input to rule `parse_bam`

```
rule bam:
    output:
        temp('a.bam'),
        temp('a.bam.bai'),
    shell:
         "code to make bam and bai"

rule parse_bam:
    input:
        'a.bam'
    output:
        'b.bam'
    shell:
         """
         samtools view {input} chr1 > {output}
         """
```

Comment: `sys.argv`, of course! I added an example of code where final files are removed. I should think to construct my workflow differently. Thank you for your time